# Duplicate an Umbraco site to another account

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, umbraco, umbraco7

Is it possible to duplicate a live Umbraco site which we have full access to (Backoffice, passwords etc.) and copy its content into another account? 
The idea is that we want a clone of the live site to *practice on* without danger of changing something and accidentally ruining the currently working and published live site.

To simplify, we have:

> 1. A working **live** Umbraco site with admin privileges so we can access all files.
> 2. A **new**, separate Umbraco account which is essentially a blank canvas with access to all files.

We would like to duplicate all the files and content from the live site to the new account just to have something that closely resembles the live site to practice building widgets etc.

We are working in **Visual Studio 2012** with **C#** and **Razor** and want to use the latest version of **Umbraco CMS** (currently 7.3.0-beta Prerelease according to NuGet Package Manager).

Have I got the right idea with this approach or is there a better way? I am aware of [Umbraco Courier](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2) but would like to know if there are any options other than a paid-for add-on.

If this is the best approach, what is the procedure, and if not, what are the options and why are they preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily by copying the files to a new environment, restoring a backup of the database to a new environment and then updating the connection string in the web.config. This will give you a working copy of the live site. If you are looking for a continuously synchronised solution then that is a different matter, Courier has never worked for me reliably.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was hoping it would be this straghtforward.

Comment: Just don't forget to set the correct file permissions on your new environment

Comment: Courier wouldn't be enough for this as it mainly handles content related items (everything in the database). You would still need to clone/copy your custom files for configurations and plugins and all that. The best solution is as ProNotion mentions, to clone the files and database and make sure to edit the connectionstring. You might also want to delete the App_Data/TEMP/* files and App_Data/umbraco.config to have Umbraco automatically regenerate those in the "new setup".

Comment: These folders are mostly temporary Lucene indexes and caches - it would most likely work as it is, but to avoid problems they should be regenerated.
An added benefit of doing this copy/clone, is that you actually once in a while get your backup/restore process tested to ensure you have everything you need in case of a data loss!
For development purposes this is the optimal way to handle it. Courier is more focused on a backoffice experience of syncronizing content between test/staging/live environments.